# Change to a specific directory in :Explorer

Tags: netrw

How do I change the directory when I'm already in `:Explorer`?  Sometimes I open it up by saying `:vs .` and from there I want to go to `~/vim/` or something.  I'm not sure how to do that without traversing the tree to get there or quitting and typing `:vs ~/vim/`.  Isn't there some way to change the directory when you're already in `:Explorer`?

I searched using F1 but didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you looking for `:Explore ~/vim` ?

Comment: @janos No, I think I said I'm not in the question itself.  Unless you're saying you can do that when you're already in :Explore

Comment: This works for me. Not for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply opening a directory for "editing" works just fine for me:

```
:e ~/vim
```